# JPA : Issue with foreign keys, multiple primary keys and many to one relation

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, toplink

I am working on an Java/J2EE web application. The persistence of data is made by JPA/TopLink. And I have an issue with this entity :

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "articlecatalogue_has_article", catalog = "artisance", schema = "public")
@NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name = "ArticlecatalogueHasArticle.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM ArticlecatalogueHasArticle a"), @NamedQuery(name = "ArticlecatalogueHasArticle.findByArcIntId", query = "SELECT a FROM ArticlecatalogueHasArticle a WHERE a.articlecatalogueHasArticlePK.arcIntId = :arcIntId"), @NamedQuery(name = "ArticlecatalogueHasArticle.findByArtIntId", query = "SELECT a FROM ArticlecatalogueHasArticle a WHERE a.articlecatalogueHasArticlePK.artIntId = :artIntId"), @NamedQuery(name = "ArticlecatalogueHasArticle.findByAhaDecQuantite", query = "SELECT a FROM ArticlecatalogueHasArticle a WHERE a.ahaDecQuantite = :ahaDecQuantite"), @NamedQuery(name = "ArticlecatalogueHasArticle.findByAhaDecPrixvente", query = "SELECT a FROM ArticlecatalogueHasArticle a WHERE a.ahaDecPrixvente = :ahaDecPrixvente")})
public class ArticlecatalogueHasArticle implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected ArticlecatalogueHasArticlePK articlecatalogueHasArticlePK;
    @Column(name = "aha_dec_quantite")
    private BigDecimal ahaDecQuantite;
    @Column(name = "aha_dec_prixvente")
    private BigDecimal ahaDecPrixvente;
    @JoinColumn(name = "art_int_id", referencedColumnName = "art_int_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Article article;
    @JoinColumn(name = "arc_int_id", referencedColumnName = "arc_int_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Articlecatalogue articlecatalogue;
```

And the multiple primary keys :

```
@Embeddable
public class ArticlecatalogueHasArticlePK implements Serializable {
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "arc_int_id")
    private int arcIntId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "art_int_id")
    private int artIntId;
```

When I try to make persistent an ArticlecatalogueHasArticle entity I have this following error :

```
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [TOPLINK-4002] (Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.1 (Build b60e-fcs (12/23/2008))): oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERREUR: une valeur NULL viole la contrainte NOT NULL de la colonne « arc_int_id »
Error Code: 0
Call: INSERT INTO artisance.public.articlecatalogue_has_article (aha_dec_prixvente, aha_dec_quantite, art_int_id, arc_int_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [null, 1, null, null]
```

Whereas the fields arcIntId and artIntId are not null in the entity which I want to make persistent. I think the problem is due to the double instance of the columns "art_int_id" and "arc_int_id" in the ArticlecatalogueHasArticlePK and in the ArticlecatalogueHasArticle @JoinColumn, but I am not sure and I do not know how to solve the problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you assign values to `arcIntId` and `artIntId` before attempting to make the entity persistent?  It would help to post the code snippet that's causing the exception (with enough lines preceding the offending line to provide some context).

Comment: Yes, I checked with the debugger that values are assigned to `arcIntId` and `artIntId`. And the exception was thrown when I did `em.persist(aha);`, with `aha` an occurrence of ArticlecatalogueHasArticle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure you are setting the id values in the articlecatalogueHasArticlePK, if you do not set them, then they will be null.

You could also remove the articlecatalogueHasArticlePK, and use a IdClass instead of an EmbeddedId.  Then you only need to put @Id on your ManyToOne, and don't need any duplicates.

You could also put insertable/updateable false on the basics and true on the ManyToOne if you want to pick the ids up from the relationships.

See,
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Primary_Keys_through_OneToOne_and_ManyToOne_Relationships

Answer (score 0):

You must use the [`@MapsId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapsId.html) annotation on the two ManyToOne associations.

Comment: The problem is the application runs on a Glassfish 2.xx, so with the Java EE 5 SDK and the annotation @MapsId does not exist in it.